# Error when incrementing app version code using Intel XDK

Tags: android, cordova, intel, intel-xdk

When I increase the app version code to 1.1, I get an error:

> An unexpected error occurred while attempting to build the
>   application.

If I don't update the app version code, Google Play Store gives me an error:

> You need to use a different version code for your APK because you
>   already have one with version code 1

[image]

How to correctly update the app version code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with intel xdx, but the version code is usually a number like:

versionCode: `11`

The versionName could be `1.1` in that case.

So using `11` instead of `1.1` might help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today and I was looking here :

https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/articles/android-and-crosswalk-cordova-version-code-issues

And then, I found this usefull topic !

BUT, in the project settings, I just got TODAY after the maj 2727 the version code in the settings ... I wasn't able to change it before.